# Error message in MySQL Workbench: 'local instance 3306 - warning - not supported' what does this mean?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am very new to using MySQL Workbench. I have just noticed the error message as stated above. I have inserted a screenshot of it.

[error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCsx6.png)

Honestly I am not too sure what to try - as like I said I have not used this before so am very new to the application. However, looking at XAMPP manager, it does say that MySQL is running, and using port 3306.

[screenshot of servers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBngF.png)

Comment: This happens to us a lot. 

It's due (in our case) to us running MariaDB (which is closely based on MySQL). Workbench is bleating because it's not _real_ MySQL. It's never caused us any issues.

Comment: And XAMPP comes with MariaDB, which is not mysql. And that closely based thing is not really true any more as the two applications forked 8 years ago and have several pages long list of incompatibilities...

Comment: oh okay great! so I don't need to change anything, just use it as it is? Thanks so much!